# get the total sales in custom object

Tags: custom-object, custom-report-type

I have 2 custom object 'Supervisor' and 'Engineers',
in OPPORTUNITY, The user can get to select the engineer depending on the picklist of group he chooses then the lookup will just display all the engineers that is in that group.
Per group has 1 supervisor. This is now my question, I need to get the total sales of the opportunity of the engineers and the total sales of all of the engineers in a certain group. What approach can i use? Thanks in advance and respect post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using Summary or Matrix type of Reports.

1. Create a Matrix report and you can summarise it upto two level on each direction (Horizontal,Vertical)

Select Group Name as first Summary level and Engineers as second summary level for Vertical summaries. As an additional feature you can group Opportunity stage at Horizontal level. Now you will be able to get Stage specific revenue for each group and all engineers under that group.

2. Create Summary report and you can summarise it using Group Name and Engineers. You can create buckets to group your opportunity stages.